# I have created my libary, but can't open it

Tags: python, oop, python-import

I have created a libary that consists of

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import math
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as sfs
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_sequential_feature_selection as plot_sfs
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

class preprocessing:
   def __init__ (self, data_name):
       self.data_name = data_name
       
   def get_data(self):
       df = pd.read_pickle('{}.pkl'.format(self.data_name))
       df = df[2:].reset_index(drop=True).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
       return df
    
   def drop_breaks(df, tag_name, paper_on_value):
        df = df[df[tag_name]==paper_on_value].drop(tag_name, axis=1)
        return df

   def one_hot(df, tag_name):
       ohe = OneHotEncoder()
       feat_array = ohe.fit_transform(df[[tag_name]]).toarray()
       feat_label = np.array(ohe.categories_).ravel()
       cat_feat = pd.DataFrame(feat_array, columns=feat_label)
       df = pd.concat([df, cat_feat], axis=1)
       df = df.drop(tag_name, axis=1)
       return df
```

I have saved it as machine_learning.py

and when I want to load it with

```
import machine_learning as ml
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine_learning'
```

I have saved both files on the same location

Comment: How are you running these files? Using what `python` command? And what's the current working directory?

Comment: All the code that I created is presented

Comment: Yes, but you have to run it somehow. As in, you have to open a command prompt and type something like `python my_other_file.py`. I'm asking about *that* side of the process.

Comment: I use spyder, machine_learning.py is the libary, and I have created second .py file to run it.

Comment: This seems like you might be missing some configuration in spyder, such as creating a project.  To troubleshoot this, I suggest trying to run your program from the command line to see if the problem is with spyder or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The File should be in the same folder to be used as a custom library/module

```
Project Folder/
├─ app.py
├─ machine_learning.py
```

As shown in the above file structure then you can use it

or

Have to enter the full path of the library file

Comment: So, no, it doesn't *have* to be in any particular directory. `machien_learning.py` just has to be on the import path. If the OP was trying to create a library, then it should probably be packaged then installed with `pip`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's possible that the OP means they created a module and don't really want to create a separate package.

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the confusion, this is all new for me. I think I have created a package